# Metric tensor and its inverse

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, linear-algebra

1. Is it **always** allowed to represent the [metric tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) $g_{\mu \nu}$ in [General Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Relativity) as a $4\times 4$ matrix?
2. If the last one is represented for example with a $4\times 4$ matrix $\mathbf{A}\in{\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}}$ is it always true that its metric inverse $g^{\mu \nu}$ is the **ordinary** matrix inverse $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ which one can calculate with ordinary linear algebra methods?

Maybe this question may sound silly, but I've understood that in differential geometry, also simple things become complicated...

Answer (score 2):

1) yes.

2) yes.  So long as you're describing the ordinary physical 4-D space of standard general relativity.  You can get weirdness when you describe null subsurfaces of 4-D space, and the ordinary inverse does not exist.  I can point you to the part of my diss where I discuss that if you're especially curious.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: When considering the metric **at a single point**, it is a good old fashioned matrix we all know and love from elementary linear algebra.

Long Answer: Well, there is some subtlety to this question, because the entries of a metric tensor in local coordinates $x^{\mu}$ appear to be **functions** that are sufficiently smooth. Smooth functions form a *ring* and **not** a field! So the linear algebra has some intricacies.

This is **flawed reasoning!** Why? Because we specify the metric **on a tangent space** $g(-,-)_{p}:T_{p}M\times T_{p}M\to\mathbb{R}$. We just demand that as we "vary $p\in M$ smoothly" that the metric  $g$ varies "smoothly" with $p$ (in some sense).

Having made a choice of coordinates $x^{\mu}$ in some neighborhood $U$ of $p$, we have some basis vectors for the tangent space $\left.\mathbf{e}_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}\right|_{p}$ of $T_{p}M$. These enable us to determine the components of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}=g(\mathbf{e}_{\mu},\mathbf{e}_{\nu})_{p}$ which is a matrix as you noted in (1).

But this is **at a single point** $p\in M$. The values of $g_{\mu\nu}$ vary smoothly with $p$. Here's the counter-intuitive behaviour of the metric: we write $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ to indicate the component is a "function" of the coordinates, and it should be smooth "in the obvious way". The problem is that invertibility isn't guaranteed for arbitrary matrices with components being smooth functions! So we work with a very special subcollection of such matrices.